# Getting network manager on the gnome panel

Tags: gnome-panel, network-manager

I've just installed 10.10 from a minimal iso. I've installed gnome-core and the network manager (among a few other things), and I've added the notification area to the panel.

According to the system monitor, nm-applet is currently running, but I can't see it in the notification area. How can I resolve this?

EDIT:

I've noticed that if I click really close to the right of the notification area I get a nm-applet dropdown box but it says "device not managed" under "Wired Network" (I am connected to the internet though), yet there is no nm-applet graphic.

Comment: Are there other icons in the notification area that are displaying?

Comment: Nah, there aren't. But the indicator applet and clock are there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see "device not managed" then probably your NIC is indeed not managed from network-manager.

Please check the following file:

/etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf

What does the following section say ?:

[ifupdown]
managed=?

if it's set to "false", switch it to "true", save the file and run a:

"sudo service network-manager restart"

Answer (score 2):

Ok I tracked down a Ubuntu forum Thread about it here

[nm-applet icon missing from panel](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1506720)

One of the solutions which hasen't been mentioned here is the work around mentioned in launchpad.

> OK, weird, I haven't had this problem for a couple of days now. The thing I did was to right click the panel, select 'properties', and then disable 'expand', wait till the panel resizes and then enable 'expand'

Try this one and if it doesn't work there are a few others in post.

Hope this help's

Comment: I just gave that a go. Alas, it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: The other solutions in the thread didn't help. I tried the one that involves going into network connections, but there isn't any connection to select.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have `Notification area` since you did a minimal install.

All you need to do it to right click on the top panel, `"Add to Panel"` and search for `"Notification area"` and you can see `NetworkManager` applet reappear.

I can't confirm this since right now I am not on an Ubuntu machine, but this is a known problem. People usually come across this and even including me

Comment: I had added the notification area.

Answer (score 1):

According to your edit, maybe the notification area has been resized so small that it can't show the nmapplet inside it.  Try unlocking it and moving it around, or add some other icon to the panel and see if it shows up.